# Find a node at the same level in a tree for a given node?

Tags: java, binary-tree

I have to find the nodes in the same level when one of the level member is given as input. But I was unable to get the estimated output. I did not find where my code wrong. I am giving my code at which I was unable to recognize the mistake. Can some one explain the mistake I did in the code?

My sample input and output is,

```
       10

     /   \

   17     12

 /  \    /  \

10  8     1 3
```

Ex:-

Input:17

output :12

Input:1

output:8 or 3 or 10

Here is my sample code,

```
public void printNode(Node node)
{
    Queue<Node> que = new LinkedList<Node>();
    Queue<Node> aux = new LinkedList<Node>();
    que.add(root);
    while(!que.isEmpty())
    {
        Node temp = que.poll();
        System.out.println(temp+" ");
        if(temp.left != null)
        {
            que.add(temp.left);
            aux.add(temp.left);
        }
        if(temp.right != null)
        {
            que.add(temp.right);
            aux.add(temp.right);
        }
        if(aux.contains(node))
        {
            while(!aux.isEmpty())
            {
                if(aux.poll() != node)
                System.out.print(aux.poll()+" ");               
            }
        }
        else
        {
            aux.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post [mcve] , including test data

Answer (score 0):

Nodes with same level after target node are not enque `aux` when you check `aux.contains(node)`.

Comment: Why they are not en-queued into the queue?What should I do in order to en-queue those nodes into the queue?

Comment: My idea, you'd better maintain `aux` queue with item as Node with level which can be parentNode.level + 1, do not poll/de-queue item until find target Node , poll all Node with less level before and continue. When find a Node with upper level, all item of `aux` is your result.